# Export MySQL query log to JSON format

Tags: mysql, performance, log, slow-log

Is there any tool which is capable of exporting MySQL query log to JSON format (or any other structured format)?

Comment: You could set `log_output=TABLE`, giving you more  options for parsing (or just querying directly). It's a dynamic global variable so it can be changed without a restart. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-destinations.html.

Comment: Switch to Percona Server and use the Audit plugin or install and use McAfee audit plugin. This doesnt provide slow log information but that's not not in your original requirements.

Comment: @eroomydna that would work, but switching server software to parse logs often isn't an option.

Comment: @dartonw that would also work, but log_output=TABLE has query time resolution up to a second (I'm not sure if that's still true for 5.6/5.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many niche projects on Github to do that, most of them haven't been updated in years. Since percona-toolkit is a very common software used to analyze MySQL I feel that utilizing it is the best option. In the code below I use popular `pt-query-digest` with `--filter` hack to execute arbitrary code:

```
# pt-query-digest --filter to_json.pl --no-report slow.log > slow.json

# cat to_json.pl
print Transformers::encode_json($event) . "\n";                                                                                                               
1
```

The `1` at the end of to_json.pl is important, and the code needs to be placed in its own file - CLI inline --filter code is put into parentheses `()`.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, go to [McAfee audit plugin](https://github.com/mcafee/mysql-audit) as it's compatible with MySQL from version 5.1 to latest GA. This plugin outputs in json nicely for you and you can filter nicely on the events you do and do not want.